# Why is compactness needed for proof that interval outer measure is its length

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I read some proofs that show that the outer measure $m^*(I)$ of an interval is equal to its length $l(I)$, i.e. $m^*(I)=l(I)$, where for an interval $I=[a,b]$, we have $l(I)=b-a=m^*(I)$.

I understand the part that $m^*(I) \leq l(I)$, but for the other direction $m^*(I) \geq l(I)$, I could not see why the proofs really wanted to use the compactness property of $I$ (being bounded and closed). From what I read, outer measure of an interval $I$ is:

$$
m^*(I) = \inf \bigg\{\sum_{j\in J} l(j) \bigg\}
$$

where $J$ forms an open covering of $I$, and $j$ refers to any open interval inside the open covering $J$ - so that the outer measure gets the infimum of the sum above for all open coverings of $I$.

Since we have (for sure) that $I \subseteq J$, shouldn't it hold trivially that $m^*(I) \geq l(I)$ ? given that whether $J$ is finite or infinite countable, it should be able to cover all elements of $I$.

So why do we need to guarantee (using compactness and the Heine Borel theorem) that there is a $J$ with finite cardinality $|J| \neq \infty$ that covers $I$ to show that $m^*(I) \geq l(I)$ ?

Comment: What if you tried to define a measure on $\Bbb Q$ by the same method?

Comment: The statement $I \subset J$ is not correct.

Comment: Yes $(I)$ is a cover of $I$ by intervals. But the definition of outer measure is the $\inf$ over all such covers, so what follows trivially from this is $m_*(I)\le|I|$, not the other way around. The non-trivial part is showing that for any cover of $I$ by inntervals the sum of the lengths is $\ge|I|$.  This is easy to see for a cover by _finitely_ many intervals. Compactness is needed to reduce to that case.

Comment: I lied.. We're talking about covers of $I$ by _open_ intervals, so if $I=[a,b]$ then $J=(I)$ is not such a cover. But for any $\epsilon>0$, $J=((a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon))$ is a cover of $I$ by open intervals; hence $m_*(I)\le|I|+2\epsilon$, hence $m_*(I)\le|I|$.

Comment: How are you getting from "whether $J$ is finite or infinite countable, it should be able to cover all elements of $I$" to $m^*(I)\geq l(I)$?  Yes, every element of $I$ is contained in some element of $J$, but why would that imply $\sum_{j\in J}l(j)\geq l(I)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey, I think you got into the heart of it, I concluded that $\sum_{j \in J}l(j) \geq l(I)$, as I thought that since every element of $I$ is in some element (interval) of $J$, adding up the lengths of all of those intervals $j \in J$ would 'trivially' be greater than the $l(I)$, i.e. since some $j \in J$ overlap... But from your answer, there seems to be way for $I$ to be covered by elements of $J$ and yet $\sum_{j \in J}l(j) \geq l(I)$ does not trivially follow... I think there's a gap with how I picture $J$, can you give an example why $\sum_{j \in J}l(j) \geq l(I)$ is not trivial?

Comment: @EricWofsey, or is it a matter of strict vs weak inequality?, i.e. it is trivial to have $\sum_{j \in J} l(j) > l(I)$, but to have $\sum_{j \in J} l(j) \geq l(I)$, we need to use the Heine Borel theorem? so that $|J|$ is finite?

Comment: You're thinking about this wrong.  If you're claiming it's trivial, the burden is on _you_ to prove it!  I think you are assuming that "length" has some properties that seem intuitively obvious, but those properties need to be proved and their proofs are far from obvious!

Comment: @EricWofsey, yes I think am getting more why it is far from obvious as you rightly said, but just to clear up my understanding, we need the Heine Borel theorem to conclude $\geq$, (i.e. there's a possibility to have equality) since strict inequality $>$ easily follows from the sub-additivity of outer measure?

Comment: No, that's completely wrong.  Proving $\geq$ is _weaker_ than proving $>$.  Sub-additivity of outer measure is useless because you don't know $l(j)$ is the same as $m^*(j)$ yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98563/discussion-between-link-l-and-eric-wofsey).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By definition of $inf$ there exists an open covering $J$ such that

$$m^*(I)+\epsilon\geq \sum_{j\in J}l(j).$$

But $I$ is compact, so without lost of generality you can choose $J$ finite. However  $J$ is an open finite cover of $I$, so it is clear that

$$\sum_{j\in J}l(j)\geq b-a=l(I).$$

Thus for each $\epsilon>0$ you have that

$$m^*(I)\geq l(I)-\epsilon\to_{\epsilon\to 0^+} l(I);$$

this means $m^*(I)\geq l(I)$